# Return Ajax request to a web page / not url line

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, nodemcu

I wish to send and receive data with a **Nodemcu**, works fine if I enter on browser address bar, but not on my own web page

i.e. if I `enter 192.168.1.14/But1` (or But2) works fine
But using the web page below it shows the status `returns` 0 And `no data`.
The **NodeMCU** is receiving OK as shown on the serial monitor
I wish to have a number of different pages access the web sever, so do not wish to send them from the **NodeMcu** so their web address is not the same as the server

**NodeMCU** program

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

// Replace with your network
const char* ssid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
ESP8266WebServer server(80);   //instantiate server at port 80 (http port)

void setup(void) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password); //begin WiFi connection
    Serial.println("");

    // Wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    server.on("/But1", []() {
        Serial.println("But1");
        server.send(200, "text/html", "But1_Click");
    });

    server.on("/But2", []() {
        Serial.println("But2");
        server.send(200, "text/html", "But2_Click");
    });

    server.begin();
    Serial.println("Web server started!");
}

void loop(void) {
    server.handleClient();
}
```

> Web page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function sendAJAX(name) {

            var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            myRequest.open('GET', 'http://192.168.1.14/' + name, true);

            myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (myRequest.readyState === 4) { // && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('readyState1').innerHTML =
                        myRequest.readyState;
                    document.getElementById('status1').innerHTML = this.status;
                    document.getElementById('ajax-content').innerHTML =
                        myRequest.responseText;
                }
            };
            myRequest.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>AJAX Test</h1>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX('But1')">Button 1</button>
    <button onclick="sendAJAX('But2')">Button 2</button>
    <p id="readyState1">Ready</p>
    <p id="status1">Status</p>
    <div id="ajax-content">Reply</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after much searching.
Just in case this may help others see solution

The problem was caused by different domain name.

```
1 Solution add an iframe to web page,

 <p><iframe name="ifdata" src="http://192.168.1.15"></iframe></p> // address of your 
 NodeMCU
 can be set to style="width:0; height:0; border:0; border:none" so it will not be 
 shown.

2 On server add, (mydata is a String holding the data) 

 client.println("<html><head></head><body>");
 client.println("<script>top.postMessage('"+mydata+"', 'Web Page Domain'); 
 </script>");
 client.println("</body></html>");

 // Or equivalent server.on("/", [](){xxxx} send.
 // This will send your data (mydata) to the calling web page using the postMessage 
 //   method

3 Add <div>indata</div> to the web page so it can be displayed

4 Add Javascript to web page to receive the post.

 function receiveMessage(event)
 {
    if (event.origin !== "http://192.168.1.15") { // address of your NodeMCU
     return;
   }
 document.getElementById('indata').innerHTML = event.data; // store data
 }
 window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);  // add Listner
```

Now when the page loads it will fetch the "mydata" from the NodeMCU and display it in 
"indata" on the web page, you can also add refreshIframe() routine to updat it at any time with out re loading the page.

Hope this may help